# knit_child in a loop - variable as title

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923392/knit-child-in-a-rmd-file-is-printing-unwanted-output) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892121/variable-as-title-in-rmarkdown) stackoverflow-questions, I tried to use knit-child inside a loop, containing a variable-defined title.

Instead of the variables (e.g. A, B, C) as title, I get them with # still attached (# A, # B, # C)

Parent:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r,include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
```


```{r,echo=FALSE}

titles<-LETTERS[1:3]

```

```{r,include=FALSE,echo=FALSE}
out = NULL
for (i in titles){
  out = c(out, knit_child('Child.Rmd'))
}
```


`r paste(out, collapse='\n')`
````

Child:

````
---
title: "Untitled"

output: html_document
---


```{r,echo=FALSE,results='asis'}

cat("\n\n # ", i,"\n")

```

```{r,echo=FALSE,results='asis'}

cat("\n\n This text is about ", i,"\n")

```
````

Output:

[image]

**While I would prefer:**

[image]

Comment: No time to check this, but please try to replace `cat("\n\n # ", i,"\n")` with `cat("\n\n# ", i,"\n")` (no whitespace before the hash).

Comment: @CL. you're correct. If you paste it into an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#` character only indicates a heading in markdown if it is the first character of the line.

`cat("\n\n # ", i,"\n")` produces two new lines, then one space and *then* the `#`. Remove the whitespace to fix the issue:

```
cat("\n\n# ", i,"\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [`knit_expand`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/knit-expand.html) function.

You create your Child.Rmd as

````
# {{current_title}}

This text is about {{current_title}}

Remember that `current_title` is a literal string, so
if you want use it in code then must be quoted:

<!-- Use `current_title` in chunk name to avoid duplicated labels -->

```{r {{current_title}}} 
data.frame({{current_title}} = "{{current_title}}")
```
````

Then your main document shoud looks like this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r,include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
```


```{r,echo=FALSE}

titles<-LETTERS[1:3]

```

```{r,include=FALSE,echo=FALSE}
expanded_child <- lapply(
    titles
    ,function(xx) knit_expand("Child.Rmd", current_title = xx)
    )

parsed_child <- knit_child(text = unlist(expanded_child))

```

`r parsed_child`
````

Results:

[image: How it looks]

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `pandoc.header`instead of `Cat`.

```
i = 1
pander::pandoc.header(i, level = 1)
> # 1

pander::pandoc.header(paste0("Subheading ", i), level = 3)
> ### Subheading 1
```